# It works if use 'int' but fails when I use 'long' . How do I make this function return long

Tags: java, string, long-integer

the function only returns value when I declare 'n' as int, but returns null when i use 'long'.

Given a string and a value n, the string should be concatenated n number of times. in the concatenated string, we will take the first n characters in that string and return the number of letter 'a' that appeared.

Print a single integer denoting the number of letter a's in the first n letters of the infinite string created by repeating s infinitely many times.

In this function, two parameters are passed, a string and a long value. The code works very well if use an int value instead of long. Please how do i fix this long and int issue ?

```
public class StringLettersRepeat {
    static long repeatedString(String s, long n) {
        String string = "";
        int count =0;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            string+=s;
        }

        char[] strChar = string.toCharArray();
        char[] result = new char[(int) n];

        for(int i=0; i<strChar.length;i++){
            result[i]=strChar[i];
        }
        for(char str : result){
            if('a'==str){
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long result = repeatedString("a", 1000l);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I expect the output to return a value, which is the number of count.
for example, if I enter string "aba" and n=7, it should return 5.

But if i pass in a string, say 'a' with n=100000000000, it's supposed to return 100000000000 but it doesn't work. Please what's possibly wrong with my code?

Comment: "but it doesn't work" What happens when you run the code in this case? Do you get an error? If so, what is the complete error message? If not, what is the actual output?

Comment: hey @Code-Apprentice, it doesn't return any error. If i use integer value for n, and pass a string, the code works perfectly well... but if i use long value and pass a string, it doesn't run, it returns a blank page.

Comment: Appending to a string in a long loop is very inefficient. Is your function just not finishing?

Comment: @khelwood If I change everywhere the long is being used to int, the code works fine. But if pass in a long value, I will obviously modify the code and it should return a value, but instead it returns blank page.

Comment: so let's say, we want to pass a string and a long value on this code, is there anything i'm supposed to change again in the code to make it work with the long parameter passed?

Comment: How about you just don't create the absurdly long string? It does not appear to be necessary.

Comment: @khelwood ohhhhh... i see... but how else do i loop there? because I want to concatenate the strings.

Comment: You don't need to concatenate the strings. You should be able to figure out logically how many a's would be in the hypothetical string based on knowing where the a's are in the input string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201437/discussion-between-thomas-okonkwo-and-khelwood).

Comment: Arrays are indexed by 'int' values, thus there can be no more than 2G elements in an array.  The length of a String is an 'int', therefore cannot exceed 2G.  It therefore follows that your 'n' argument is limited to 2G, and consequently there is no point in making it 'long' with the rest of the code as written.

Comment: What does 'return a blank  page' mean?  Nothing in this code has to do with 'pages'.  I suspect you mean in just fails to complete. Is there some exception message you're overlooking?

Comment: @another-dave `n` is not limited to `int`, it can be a `long`. Of course, the suggested *implementation* in the question is restricted that way, but that doesn't mean that the method itself is, it just needs another implementation, e.g. the one already provided in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566979/5221149), more than one hour before your comment.

Comment: @Andreas - understood, hence my use of "with the rest of the code as written".  My intent was to explain why his code could not work, rather than duplicating your excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given your example of calling `repeatedString("aba", 7)`, the resulting string would be `"abaabaa"`, and has 5 a's, as you said.

But, you don't actually have to build that result string. Instead, realize that the result string is the original string repeated `2` times, plus the first `1` characters of the string, both of which can easily be calculated using division and remainder math:

```
long repeats = n / s.length();
long extra = n % s.length();
```

Now, if you count the number of a's in the string, you can multiply by `repeats`. You don't need to repeat the counting operation. If you then also count the number of a's in the first `extra` characters of string, you have your final result.

```
int countFull = 0, countExtra = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') {
        countFull++;
        if (i < extra)
            countExtra++;
    }
}
```

Then calculate the total and return it:

```
return countFull * repeats + countExtra;
```

This code also runs a lot faster, because you only have to iterate `s` once, it doesn't matter for performance what `n` is, and you don't copy any characters, so it also uses a lot less memory. It actually doesn't use any memory.

Big-O is:
  Performance: *O(m)* where `m` is length of input string.
  Memory: *O(1)*
Neither is related to `n`.

*Test*

```
System.out.println(repeatedString("aba", 7));
System.out.println(repeatedString("a", 100000000000L));
```

*Output*

```
5
100000000000
```

Comment: Wow! Andreas, this solution works like magic. Now I understand perfectly well. It's clear now why my code won't work: there was no use to build that string result, but instead use the division and remainder as demonstrated in your solution - perfect!. Thanks much, Andreas